# Django QuerySet Limit hits database too many times?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I've recently stumbled upon a massive bottleneck on a production website only after updating from Django 1.11 > 2.1

Here is my simple slice of code;

```
pages = Page.objects.filter(cat="news_item").order_by('-created')[:2]
```

This in turn, creates around ~30 queries, around the number of pages under that specific filter.

I have now implemented a somewhat hacky way to resolve the 32 queries which i'm not satisfied with.

```
pages = [Page.objects.filter(cat='news_item').order_by('-created')[i] for i in range(0,2)]
```

**Speed is notably effected, a few other chunks of code used this method which caused >400 queries per page load - I have since adapted these to use a combination of the above code & Model.objects.raw**

*Did something change in Django 2.0/2.1 that I missed or does the [:2] limit not work correctly?*

Comment: Your original query looks fine at a first glance. Are you using a custom Manager or QuerySet?

Comment: @DanielHepper Nothing custom for this which is why it's got me really confused.

Also not using any custom manager - all database interaction uses out of the box django ORM

Answer (score 1):

Weirdest issue/bug/confusion I've ever seen.

Doing the following only queries **once**;

```
pages = Page.objects.filter(cat="news_item").order_by('-created')[:2:1]
```

I noted on the django documentation here that it states
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets

> Generally, slicing a QuerySet returns a new QuerySet – it doesn’t evaluate the query. An exception is if you use the “step” parameter of Python slice syntax. For example, this would actually execute the query in order to return a list of every second object of the first 10:
>
> `Entry.objects.all()[:10:2]`

So, using this weird trick above - it forces this basic piece of code to evaluate and query the database immediately, only causing one database query instead of 30+